# How to update Laravel Installer "laravel/installer" to latest version?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, command-line-interface, installation

I tried to update my laravel/installer using the command:

`composer global update laravel/installer`

But it only upgraded its minor version (assuming that it uses Semantic Versioning).

```
Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
  - Updating laravel/installer (v2.1.0 => v2.3.0): Downloading (100%)
```

Then I execute the update command again:

`composer global update laravel/installer`

But outputs:

```
Nothing to install or update
```

I now uses `PHP 7.4.4 (cli)` obtained using `php -v` so I assume that it should be able to upgrade to latest which is `Laravel Installer 3.0.1`.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What does `composer global why-not laravel/installer:"3.0.1"` tell you?

Comment: @NicoHaase I did not arrive to `why-not` sub-command since it was fixed by "reinstalling" the package.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If running `composer global update laravel/installer` is not enough to upgrade the the desired version, there might be package dependencies that restricts the upgrade to the latest.

I do not know if there is a `composer` option to do that on `global` scope but the following commands works for me:

```
# uninstall the package
composer global remove laravel/installer

# reinstall
composer global require laravel/installer
```

The 1st process outputs the outdated packages dependencies that are removed with the `laravel/installer` package.

Then the 2nd process installs the latest `laravel/installer` with the updates dependencies.

Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation) does not include how to update the installer package yet.

---

**Update:** Adding *Documentation* link on how to update a composer package.

`composer require` specific version [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require).

> `php composer.phar require "vendor/package:2.*" vendor/package2:dev-master`

As we can see, specific version could be supplied after the colon.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require

Comment: I just upgraded from Laravel 7 to 8, and running `composer global require "laravel/installer:^4.0"` did the trick for me (i.e., without `remove`ing first).

Comment: Thanks, you are a lifesaver

Answer (score 3):

your php version is restricting it.
it's probably because you have multiple PHP versions installed.
update your environment variable of PHP.
then remove The Laravel installer and install it again.